# Windows 8 create a system restore disk

Tags: windows-8

Recently bought an ASUS ultrabook running Win8. However ASUS (nor most other mftr's, I hear) provide the Recovery CD/DVD any longer. In the past there was either a Recovery CD or app/instructions for creating your own upon first login to the system. Nor do they provide a Windows-8 Installation disk. In fact they don't even give you your License Key any longer, so 3rd party apps are needed to pull it out of the BIOS/Registry to record it.

I'm still waiting to hear back for an adequate response from ASUS Support on this. The first couple of attempts yielded rather useless information. Web searches don't seem to provide much either.

Windows 8 "tutorial" type sites talk alot about the new Refresh/Restore options, and also about Recovery - however all assume that your HDD will never fail, nor that you'll ever swap the HDD for a SSD, and that all you ever need is what is already there on your factory provided OEM setup hard drive.

What if it becomes corrupted? What if the disk fails (like that's never gonna happen, right?). Backups are not the issue, I've always created/maintained those, and always can restore my apps/data. I just need the Win8 OS with my valid license key and activation.

I've also looked into 3rd party disk-imaging tools, and am considering going this route to get what I need. There's no way I'm getting stuck paying for a reinstall in the event of failure, and succumbing to the "Well, you should have created a Recovery Disk option" response I can already hear tech-support parotting (from a scripted queue-card no doubt) when I call and ask how to recover a failed system.

How do I create an external System Restore Disk (DVD or USB/Ext-HDD) that will allow me to bring back my system on a newly installed HDD/SSD as it was the day the laptop was purchased?

If I get any new info, I'll update this question.
Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow it's really the right place for this - This community is dedicated to questions about programming, not just general technology use.

Comment: Not really. This post is better suited to superuser (there's hardly anything abt programming in the question, it's more about system and creating restore disks).

Answer (score 0):

You dont say what Asus you have, but mine have a utility to burn the Recovery DVD.

and here is a tutorial on how to recover from it.

http://rog.asus.com/150812012/g-series-laptops/guide-using-asus-ai-recovery-utility-dvds-to-backup-and-restore-a-g75/

Answer (score 0):

the newer asus models don't have access to the AI Recovery Burner.

The best thing I've found is to use the "Create a Recovery Drive" feature in windows 8.  It will also take the recovery/utility partition if it exists.  Supply it with a 16-32GB flashdrive and you should be set.